# login screen page getter and setter

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me? Basically I need a page that asks for a user's name on the first page of my website. This will then allow you to the home page. How can I use the person's name on the home page at the minute the home page is being over write with just a white page with what ever the person inputs on the screen before?

Login page code

```
<link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="image">
    <img src="../images/logo.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="login">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Called on form's `onsubmit`
        function tosubmit() {
            // Getting the value of your text input
            var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

            // Storing the value above into localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("mytext", mytext);

            return true;
        }

    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <center>   
        <!-- INLCUDING `ONSUBMIT` EVENT + ACTION URL --> 
        <form name="myform" onsubmit="tosubmit();" action="index.html">

            <input  id="mytext" type="text" name="data">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the home page code

```
<script>

    // Called on body's `onload` event
    function init() {
        // Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into localStorage
        var mytext = localStorage.getItem("mytext");

        // Writing the value in the document
        document.write(" "+mytext);
            }

</script>


<body onload="init();">

</body>
```

Comment: Try to inspect the localstorage what on most browser can be done via the dev tools.

Comment: Never use document.write. Use DOM methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

The page is being overwritten by `document.write`. You shouldn't use it,
see the [warning](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29) in the spec:

> **Warning!** This method has very idiosyncratic behavior. In some cases,
>   this method can affect the state of the HTML parser while the parser
>   is running, resulting in a DOM that does not correspond to the source
>   of the document (e.g. if the string written is the string
>   "`<plaintext>`" or "`<!--`"). In other cases, the call can clear the
>   current page first, as if `document.open()` had been called. In yet more
>   cases, the method is simply ignored, or throws an exception. To make
>   matters worse, the exact behavior of this method can in some cases be
>   dependent on network latency, which can lead to failures that are very
>   hard to debug. **For all these reasons, use of this method is strongly
>   discouraged**.

Your case is this one:

> In other cases, the call can clear the current page first, as if `document.open()` had been called.

To avoid that, you can use DOM methods:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mytext));
```